# Not able to find the com.google.android.gms.cast packages

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I've updated the SDK and all my libraries but I still can not find the com.google.android.gms.cast package in the Google Play Services api.

Is there a url we can download this from to speed up the fixes for all those api changes?

EDIT: packages are there as of a few days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says on the Google Cast developer downloads that the android sender API wont be available to download until every device gets updated to Google play services 4.2. So like you said we have to sit around and wait until Google play services 4.2 is on every device

[Google Cast Downloads Page](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/downloads)

Comment: I'm at the same spot on this. These are the last few imports I can't resolve from the Android HelloText example. So there's no way to get it to compile yet? Must be some way, since some apps are already integrating it.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, how are new apps coming out with chromecast support when my sdk won't update to the latest Google Play Services. I went as far as to use a dex to jar converter and used an updated APK but I am still missing a few classes.

Answer (score 2):

Google Play Services, revision 15 is now available in SDK manager

[image: Google Play Services, revision 15]

Comment: Thanks. I've been checking 2 or 3 times a day and finally it is there!

Answer (score 0):

From what I read on g+, the sdk wont be updated until all devices have the new Google Play Services, so us developers have to sit around unable to change our apps to work with the new changes while that deployment goes on.

Answer (score 0):

i can confirm as of Feb.14th the android play services revision 15 is there.
this message indicates you're still without these packages.
make sure you have the libraries, as described [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res)!